# How to update entities from data model edmx in another project c# database first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, ef-database-first

I have a problem - when I update the data model `edmx`, the entities are not up to date. See the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking if you are doing Database-First you should update the database and let the data model refresh (right-click anywhere in the .edmx and select Update Model from Database...).

Comment: it's done correcty but i want to generate the classes in another project.My project it's composed on 2 project the data model project and the entities project .the generation of code it's done iin the data model project but i want to generate the code in the other project

Comment: If you're looking for project separation, take a look [at this](http://nullablecode.com/2013/09/splitting-entity-framework-model-classes-separate-projects/)
Obviously if you are using 6.x use the appropriate Context generator.